# jQuery Datepicker showing date's after cutoff time

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I can't figure this out, I'm trying to implement a cutoff time for delivery's. I am using the cutoff time of 3pm EST or 19 UTC. However it doesn't seem to work all the time, and is allowing users to select the next day after 19 UTC. Where did I go wrong? See my code below:

```
   $("#delivery_date").datepicker( {
  minDate: minDate,
  maxDate: '+3M',
  beforeShow : function(){
    var dateTime = new Date();
    var hour = dateTime.getUTCHours()
    //If Hour is greater or equals to 3PM
    if(hour  >= 19){
        //Disable all past days including tomorrow and today
        $(this).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+2" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript Date is based off of the users system clock.  Nothing standardized and consistent.  If you want consistency you will have to implement logic that uses either a internet clock or load the milliseconds from the server for the date.  One option you can look into is moment.js

Comment: Shoot. ok.. I'll check that out.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, Javascript is based on the users' date and timezone.

If you want to add a cutoff time, you first have to know the time in your timezone, then apply that to datepicker, then apply the cutoff time based on your timezone!

I would suggest taking a look at [moment.js library](https://momentjs.com/), I found it very helpful with just this kind of issue.

My TZ is Pacific Auckland, but you can change that to your desired TZ easily.

```
// Jquery Datepicker
var setDate = moment.tz('Pacific/Auckland');
jQuery("#getdate").datepicker({
minDate: checkTime(), // set min date based on NZ timezone time
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: setDate.format('dd-mm-yy'), // get from moment above
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    buttonText: "Choose Date",
    showButtonPanel: true
  });
```

[Full code here on jsfiddle that might help you](http://jsfiddle.net/clappertrapp/s3fngpoq/)