# JQuery Date picker Cut off time

Tags: datepicker

I am using  datepicker on my florist website and  i use the following in the global default setting

```
minDate: new Date().getHours() >= 11 ? 1 : 0, // The earliest selectable date, or null for no limit
maxDate: null, // The latest selectable date, or null for no limit
```

so if it is after 11 am,  datepicker block today date (i.e same  delivery cut off  time ).

My  problem is it works on user server  time instead of my  actual  local time.

For Example: We  are in California and if the user is in New  York.  The datepicker will jump  to next day when the user time reach 11  am but it is  only 8 am for  us.

Is there a  way to  force the date picker  to work  on my local time  instead of user time?

My actual datepicker code is:

```
$(function() {
    $("#attrib-11-0").attr( 'readOnly' , 'true' );
    var array = ["2023-02-13","2023-02-14","2022-05-06","2022-05-05","2022-04-21","2022-02-11","2022-02-12","2022-02-13","2022-02-14","2022-02-15","2022-02-16","2022-01-03","2021-12-24","2021-12-23","2021-12-22","2021-12-21","2021-12-20","2021-01-09","2021-01-16","2021-01-23","2021-01-30","2020-07-03","2020-07-04","2020-11-28", "2020-11-26","2020-12-05","2020-12-12","2020-12-19","2020-12-21","2020-12-22","2020-12-23","2020-12-24","2020-12-26","2020-12-25","2020-12-28"]
  var today = new Date();
  $("#attrib-11-0").attr( 'readOnly' , 'true' );
  $("#attrib-11-0").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM dd yy',
//  minDate: +1,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      if (contains(array,string)) {
        
        return [false, '']
      } else {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0 && day != 6), ''];
      }
    },
    //beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $('#attrib-11-0').val(dateText);
    }
  });
});

function contains(a, obj) {
    var i = a.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (a[i] === obj) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you in  advance  for the help.

I looked at this thread here [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373327/jquery-datepicker-showing-dates-after-cutoff-time) but i am not sure how to adapt it to my situation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accounting for Timezone with jQuery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031218/accounting-for-timezone-with-jquery-datepicker)

Comment: it would but how can adapt it to my current code? Thank you