# Block Weekends and Holidays/Special Date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timezone

I am currently using a datepicker as  a delivery calendar based on the  code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373327/jquery-datepicker-showing-dates-after-cutoff-time)

I am not a coder and dont  know anything about jquery much.

I came up with the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12wok58g/) and works ok

However, i would like to be  able to block weekends and holidays.

How  can i add this to my datepicker?

Also the displayed time seems to be off by 1 hour which i have not clue why

my date picker code is as follow

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  // Jquery Datepicker
  var setDate = moment.tz  ('America/Los_Angeles');
  jQuery("#getdate").datepicker({
    minDate: checkTime(), // set min date based on LA timezone time
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: setDate.format('dd-mm-yy'), // get from moment above
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    buttonText: "Choose Date",
    showButtonPanel: true
  });

  function checkTime(setminDate) {
    var LATime;
    (NZTime = function() {
      LANow = moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('dddd MMMM Do YYYY HH:mm:ss');
      jQuery("#msg1").text('In LA it\'s currently ' + LANow);
    })();
    setInterval(NZTime, 1000);

    var currentTime = moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles');
    var extra = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' ';
    var start_time = moment(extra + '08:00'); // NZ time
    var end_time = moment(extra + '18:00'); // NZ time

    jQuery("#startTime").html('Start Time is: ' + start_time.format('HH:mm'));
    jQuery("#endTime").html('End Time is: ' + end_time.format('HH:mm'));
    if (moment(currentTime).isBetween(start_time, end_time)) {
      //console.log('TRUE');
      setminDate = '+0d';
      jQuery("#msg").html('It\'s before the cutoff time - you can book today!');
    } else {
      //console.log('FALSE');
      setminDate = '+1d';
      jQuery("#msg").html('It\'s AFTER the cutoff time - please book for tomorrow');
    }
    return setminDate; // ADD RETURN STATEMENT
  }

}); // end doc ready
```

Thank you  for your help  and  time

beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends  does  not work

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this parts in your code:

```
  var holidays = ["2023-06-07","2023-06-14"]; //***add your holidays
  
  jQuery("#getdate").datepicker({
    minDate: checkTime(), // set min date based on LA timezone time
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: setDate.format('dd-mm-yy'), // get from moment above
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    buttonText: "Choose Date",
    showButtonPanel: true,
//***add this part
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [ holidays.indexOf(datestring) == -1 && day != 0 && day != 6 ]
}
//***
  });
```

Also the displayed time seems to be off by 1 hour which i have not clue why -> Sorry I don't understand what you mean, maybe can you show the screenshot? I see only these times in fiddle and they looks as expected:

[image]